# Search.php gets metadata from first post

Tags: php, theme-development, wp-query, loop, search

I've got this in header.php in `<head>` section:

```
$page_color = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'page_color', true);
```

It works fine because it gets correct `page_color` for posts and pages but when I perform some search and search.php is run, it occasionally gets `page_color` of first post it finds. This is the content of search.php:

```
<?php
  if( have_posts() ) : 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php else : ?>
        Nothing found.
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Any ideas why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's just occasionally, that will *always* get you the post meta of the first post on a search results page, a taxonomy page, an archive page - any page where there are multiple posts, because the `$post` global will always be populated with the first post of any main query result.

**EDIT-**

```
if ( is_singular() ) :
    // we are viewing a single post or page
    $page_color = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'page_color', true);
else :
    // not a single post or page, use a default color
    $page_color = 'blue';
endif;
```

Comment: Hmm, I see, so what would be the workaround to get `page_color` of current page or post? Search.php should never have any `page_color` - there is no way to specify it in admin panel. I already tried `the_ID();` but it doesn't work.

Comment: This is where [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) come in handy, see my edit above. You can check what type of page you're viewing and set and output what you need based on those conditions.

Comment: You might simplify it with a ternary: `$page_color = ( is_singular() ? get_post_meta($post->ID, 'page_color', true); : 'blue' );`. But the key is the `is_singular()` conditional. Note that `is_singular()` will return true for `post`, `page`, and `attachment` post types. So if you only allow `page_color` for single blog posts, use `is_single()` instead.

Comment: Thank you guys. This obviously works fine but isn't there any "correct" way to do that? I mean - to obtain correct ID of current post/page (search.php may return null) and return false when trying to access `page_color` if such ID doesn't exist? Making it work for posts and pages using if() seems like workaround.